# Class property doesn't exist

Tags: typescript

I have been bugging on an issue, unable to find the solution. I have simplified the code to a minimum, but I still can't figure it out.

I have set up 2 basic projects with the **same** configuration for Babel and Typescript. One of my project is actually a module, which I import in the other project. Both of my projects are coded in Typescript, but each of them are transpiled to JS before I run them.

Both projects have the following Babel 7 configuration:

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = function( api ) {

  api.cache( () => process.env.NODE_ENV );

  const presets = [

    [
      "@babel/env",
      {
        targets: {
          node: "10",
          browsers: "> 0.25%, not dead" // without this line, Babel doesn't transform the class and it works.
        },
        useBuiltIns: "usage",
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript"

  ];

  const plugins = [
    // same result with or without this plugin
    // the value of loose doesn't change anything
    [ "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { loose: false } ]
  ];

  return {
    presets,
    plugins,
  };

};
```

Both projects have the following Typescript configuration:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5", // I tried multiples values for this one
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true, 
    "noEmit": true, 
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

My first test is to compile my class and run it without any module.
This is my source code:

```
//{ProjectRoot}/src/main.ts
class MOD {

  public name:string;

  constructor() {
    this.name = "Foo";
  }

  getName():string {
    return this.name;
  }

}

const mod = new MOD();
console.log(MOD)          // Output: [Function: MOD]
console.log(mod)          // Output: MOD { name: 'Foo' }
console.log(mod.getName())// Output: Foo
```

I compile and run this source code by running:

```
tsc && babel ./src --out-dir dist -x .js,.ts -D --verbose --delete-dir-on-start && node dist/main
```

Everything runs fine, and I get the expected output in my terminal.
When I look at dist/main.js, I can see that the class has been completely rewritten by the compiler.

```
//{ProjectRoot}/dist/main.js
//... some code added by Babel ...
var MOD =
/*#__PURE__*/
function () {
  function MOD() {
    _classCallCheck(this, MOD);

    _defineProperty(this, "name", void 0);

    this.name = "Foo";
  }

  _createClass(MOD, [{
    key: "getName",
    value: function getName() {
      return this.name;
    }
  }]);

  return MOD;
}();
```

If I remove the `browsers: "> 0.25%, not dead"` in the Babel configuration, the compiler only adds the _defineProperty function, but keeps the rest of the code as is.

I then moved the same code to another projects, which simulates a NPM module (but in another directory, outside of the project root).

The source code of the module is:

```
// {moduleRoot}/src/main.ts
class MOD {

  constructor() {
    this.name = "Foo";
  }

  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

}

module.exports = MOD;
```

The module is compiled using the same command as above.

Then in my project, I modified the source as follows:

```
//{ProjectRoot}/src/main.ts
//const Mod = require("../../module/dist/main"); // Works with require()
import Mod from "../../module/dist/main";        // Doesn't work with import

const mod = new Mod();
console.log(MOD)          // Output: [Function: MOD]
console.log(mod)          // Output: MOD { name: 'Foo' }
console.log(mod.getName())// Output: Foo
```

Again, it works great. I then replace the `require()` by the `import`, and things don't work anymore.
If I compile without doing the type check, then I get the correct output, meaning that Node can interpret my code.
However Typescript gives me the following error when doing the type-check:

```
src/main.ts:7:17 - error TS2339: Property 'getName' does not exist on type 'MOD'.

7 console.log(mod.getName())
```

I don't understand why the result is impacted by the way I import the module.
It seems to me that the Typescript compiler is not able to resolve the module correctly.

I have created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/h-Reser/91754a52b6d57de47c7b47ad5a556ff0) with the source codes and the compiled code.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the project is importing `module/dist/main`, and only a `.js` file exists at that path, the only type information the TypeScript compiler has for that import is what it can extract from `main.js`, which in general is going to be incomplete.  What you should probably do is have `tsc` on the module generate `.d.ts` files alongside the `.js` files.  Then `tsc` on the project will use the `.d.ts` files.  E.g., change `module/tsconfig.json` to the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

(Note that `allowJs` has to be removed because it is incompatible with `declaration`.  If you needed `allowJs`, please explain your scenario and I'll try to help you solve it.)  And compile the module with this command:

```
rm -rf dist && tsc && babel ./src --out-dir dist -x .js,.ts -D --verbose
```

You'll also have to change the export at the end of `module/src/main.ts` to:

```
export default MOD;
```

because the TypeScript compiler does not recognize assignments to `module.exports` in a `.ts` file and Babel does not support `export = MOD`.  This should work as long as all consumers of the module use a default import.  (Again, if you need to support consumers that do a plain `require`, please explain your scenario and I'll see what I can do.)

### Update

If you need an export assignment, since your `.ts` file will need to say `export = MOD` and Babel doesn't accept that, the only solution I can find is to run Babel on the JavaScript generated by `tsc` in which the `export = MOD` will have been translated to `module.exports = MOD`.  In an example configuration, `module/tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "ts-out",
    "declarationDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

and the build command is:

```
rm -rf dist ts-out && tsc && babel ./ts-out --out-dir dist -x .js,.ts -D --verbose
```

(This is assuming you have some reason to use Babel at all rather than using the JavaScript output of `tsc` directly.)

Comment: Yes, your solution works indeed. But as you said it no longer works with `require`, which is something that I want. I want anyone to be able to use my module, whether it's with CommonJS or ES Modules.When I download a package on NPM, I can usually use both systems. Take one example, [Express](https://github.com/expressjs/express), they use [module.exports](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/index.js), which is why I tried this way. I'm surprised that it doesn't work with my module. I don't really understand the difference.

Comment: See the updated answer for how to make `require` work.

Comment: I managed to do it. I think I was lacking some comprehension of the CommonJS and ES modules. Thanks a lot for looking into that, you were a big help :)